# Python typings and futures

Tags: python, future, python-asyncio, typing, concurrent.futures

I'm very glad to use [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) module in Python 3. Also, I'm very glad to use [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) instead of `twisted`, `tornado` and alternatives.

My question is how to define result of a coroutine properly?

Should we tell it's just a coroutine? Example 1:

```
async def request() -> asyncio.Future:
    pass
```

Or should we define type of result of coroutine as type of returning value? Example 2:

```
async def request() -> int:
    pass
```

If yes, then how to be with plain functions, which return futures? Example 3:

```
def request() -> asyncio.Future:
    f = asyncio.Future()
    # Do something with the future
    return f
```

Is it a right way? How then we can tell what is expected to be a result of the future?

Comment: Use the generic versions, e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Awaitable

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said, [typing.Awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Awaitable) perfectly suits the task.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should regular return value (such as `int`, `float`, `bool`, `None` and etc), but if you use it as a callable it should look like this:

```
async def bar(x: int) -> str:
    return str(x)

cbar: Callable[[int], Awaitable[str]] = bar
```

For more information: [here](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/424).

You can look at this [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3576) also for `mypy` support.

Comment: As for a type of the function, yes, that's true. But question was only about function's return type. Anyway, thank you